# Differentiate the number e (exp(1)) symbolically

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to take the derivative the a function that includes the number `e` (`exp(1)`). How can I solve symbolically using `e` (i.e., not decimal numbers). For example:

```
syms x
e=exp(1)
diff(e^-x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do

```
 syms x;
 e=exp(sym(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's rarely a good idea to assign predefined constants to variables when using the symbolic toolbox:

```
diff(exp(-x))
```